# Running unit tests in Python with a caching decorator

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, caching, django-models

So I'm working on an application that, upon import of certain records, requires some fields to be recalculated. To prevent a database read for each check, there is a caching decorator so the database read is only preformed once every n seconds during import. The trouble comes with building test cases. The following does work, but it has an ugly sleep in it.

```
# The decorator I need to patch

@cache_function_call(2.0)
def _latest_term_modified():
    return PrimaryTerm.objects.latest('object_modified').object_modified


# The 2.0 sets the TTL of the decorator. So I need to switch out 
# self.ttl for this decorated function before 
# this test. Right now I'm just using a sleep, which works

    @mock.patch.object(models.Student, 'update_anniversary')
    def test_import_on_term_update(self, mock_update):
        self._import_student()
        latest_term = self._latest_term_mod()
        latest_term.save()
        time.sleep(3)
        self._import_student()
        self.assertEqual(mock_update.call_count, 2)
```

The decorator itself looks like the following:

```
class cache_function_call(object):
    """Cache an argument-less function call for 'ttl' seconds."""
    def __init__(self, ttl):
        self.cached_result = None
        self.timestamp = 0
        self.ttl = ttl

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner():
            now = time.time()
            if now > self.timestamp + self.ttl:
                self.cached_result = func()
                self.timestamp = now
            return self.cached_result
        return inner
```

I have attempted to set the decorator before the import of the models:

```
decorators.cache_function_call = lambda x : x
import models
```

But even at the top of the file, django still initializes the models before running my `tests.py` and the function still gets decorated with the caching decorator instead of my lambda/noop one.

What's the best way to go about writing this test so I don't have a sleep. Can I set the ttl of the decorator before running my import somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the decorator class just a little bit.

At module level in `decorators.py` set the global

```
BAILOUT = False
```

and in your decorator class, change:

```
def __call__(self, func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner():
        now = time.time()
        if BAILOUT or now > self.timestamp + self.ttl:
            self.cached_result = func()
            self.timestamp = now
        return self.cached_result
    return inner
```

Then in your tests set `decorators.BAILOUT = True`, and, hey presto!-)